# PHP inside html called by ajax did not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So this is my ajax call

```
function insertModal(link)
{
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#modalInput").html(data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

And this is my html file which called by ajax

```
        <form>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h3>Input Car</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 select-container">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix light-green-text text-darken-1">date_range</i>
                        <select id="th_car_out">
                            <?php
                                include 'script/year.php';
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <label>Choose Car Year</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Everything is working good, the form show up etc, except the PHP script.

I already try changing my php script "include" to some basic php script echo "option" or even write simple echo "hi", but it still did not show anything.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: By "it still did not show anything", do you mean that the PHP code is displayed or that `#modalInput` is never updated?. Also, `success`, `error` and `complete` callbacks were replaced since _jQuery 3.0_ in favor of `done`, `fail` and `always`.

Comment: Yes, displayed. I try to put this above <form>
                            <?php
                                echo "hi";
                            ?>

And still that hi not show up.

Comment: Can you post your web server configuration? Maybe files ending in `.html` are sent to the client without being processed by PHP first. Try renaming it with the extension `.php`.

Comment: Its work. Thanks. You should put that as an answer.

Comment: I change it to .php from .html and it work out great, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the file containing PHP code with the extension `.php`, as your web server is not configured to make PHP process `*.html` files.

Answer (score 1):

are you shure that your file is with .php extension?

you can put html in your php file, but in html file is not possible to put php expression.